# Add custom CSS to angular material md-tooltip

Tags: css, angularjs, tooltip, material-design, angular-material

I am working on angular material project and i have used ***md-tooltip*** in my application and it works fine. however i want to change the look of the tooltip. basically i need to change the background and text color. I tried adding a custom class and style the same. the background color is applied to the tooltip, but the default color comes on top of that. my code is as follows.

**HTML**

```
    <button>
        <md-tooltip md-visible="$ctrl.favorites.showTooltip" class="ng-tool-tip">Favorites</md-tooltip>
        <i class="icon icon-sm" data-ng-class="$ctrl.showFavourite ? \'icon-favorite_fill\': \'icon-favorite\'"></i>
    </button>
```

**CSS**

```
    .ng-tool-tip{
        background-color:#354052;
        color:#fff;
        font-size: 13px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "!important" to color in properties

```
.ng-tool-tip{
    background-color:#354052;
    color:#fff !important;
    font-size: 13px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```